# Black flakes coming off cast iron after it was used in the oven

Tags: cast-iron

I put my Japanese made Snow Peak cast iron pots in the oven and they cam out full of black flakes. Even after i washed pots and water was running clear, paper towel was completely black after i dried my pans.  Any idea how to fix this problem? Is it safe to use pots now?